# Can I choose the kind of org that is provisioned via trialforce?

Tags: file-storage, data-storage

We have an OEM managed package and we provision new org to customers during the trial. Most of the customers run out of storage during the trial. Can we decide the kind of organization that is provisioned during trial via trialforce?

What is the best way to solve this problem? One solution is to create a case for Salesforce to provision more storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any org you want from the environment hub although if you use a template I believe that the org will be the same type as your TSO (someone will correct me if I am wrong as it has been over a year since I created my last Trialforce Org):

> The template is a snapshot or exact copy of your TSO at a specific
>   instance in time

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_create_organization.htm

> You can create new organizations directly from the Environment Hub,
>   for the following purposes.
>
> - Development — Development organizations for creating and uploading managed packages.
> - Test/Demo— Trial organizations created for test and demonstration purposes, similar to organizations created from
>     www.salesforce.com/trial. You can specify a Trialforce template for
>     creating trial organizations. This enables you to configure and test
>     exactly how your prospects experience the trial.
> - Trialforce—You can create Trialforce Source Organizations (TSOs) from the Environment Hub, as an alternative to using a Trialforce
>     Management Organization (TMO).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I have straight question and very clear objective. The question is not about Environment hub, it is about provisioning more storage in a trial org.

Comment: Your title specifically asks if you can select the type of org that is provisioned: "Can I choose the kind of org that is provisioned via trial force"... And in your question you ask "Can we decide the kind of organization that is provisioned during trial via trial force"